# Figuring out some interview questions

Tags: search

I am new in sharepoint, so i am looking for some interview question guys please help me I have some questions:
1. Suppose we have a list with lacs of records, How can we optimize the search query?
2. we want search performance and searched (words which was typed for searching) words,
3. And optimize the bad performance of search
4. Configure FBA
And if you have some interview questions please share

regards,

Comment: Can you edit this question to include the version of SharePoint and more detail on the "Bad Performance" of search. Was component in performing poorly?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding FBA,

I had implemented FBA and done this two part blog on my site. Below given are the links to my blogs that explains FBA implementation. First blog describes how to create Membership Provider and role provider and prepare the DB. Second blog describes how to make SharePoint aware of the membership providers you have created by modifying the web.config files at various levels.

Part 1:

http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Form-Based-Authentication-FBA-in-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx

Part 2: http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Form-Based-Authentication-FBA-in-SharePoint-2010-part-2.aspx

Also some basics :
[you can find here](http://mysharepointlearnings.blogspot.in/)

Comment: thanks for sharing, can you suggest me answers of 1 and 2